# Dealing with a large amount of variables

Tags: c, design-patterns, global-variables

I am writing a large C program and have one file `file.c` that contains a large number of variables. Let's say that it has a function named `func()` that is being used by other files.

Unfortunately, the function `func()` has to use a large amount of variables and since it contains a lot of code I've decided to write some functions that are used by `func()` in order to make the code more readable. Now, I have 3 main possibilities:

- Declare the variables as global.
- Declare the variables as local inside `func()` and pass these variables as arguments to functions inside `file.c` using a struct (or any other trick that you can think of).
- Declare the variables as local and instead of using other functions just throw all the code inside `func()` which will result in very long and unreadable code.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Where are the "variables" you speak of *now* ? Global? Static to `file.c` ? Local to `func()`?

Comment: Simulate classes and instances, or write in C++ or Java.

Comment: Declare the variables as local inside func() and pass these variables as arguments to functions inside file.c

Comment: @WhozCraig Now they are global.

Comment: @Hot Licks I have to write the code in C

Comment: Then simulate classes and instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the second option is the best.

over-use of global variables is considered a bad practice.

It's may be a source of poor performance in some cases because the global has to be loaded, whereas if you can keep a variable local it can be stored in a register.

Also, code reuse is much easier. The function that receives a parameter is more general. It can be called in various use cases. The function that uses the global can be performed in only one context.

In addition, globals are available, and thus, very probably, also used everywhere in the program. This means that they are accessed and written to from many places. Validating their values can be really cause an overhead.

Bottom line: Modular code is really more readable and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

A "large number of variables" sounds to me like a mess that can be organized into one or several structs. If I were you, the first thing I would do would be to analyze file.c in order to have a good idea of which are the most used variables and the relation they hold to each other, with that information I would then group the variables into structs that could then be passed as pointers to the functions. The least used variables have a reasonable chance to become constants at the function call level, so be aware of that. I wouldn't be surprised if I found variables with duplicated meaning and content, so I believe you have great deal of chance for optimization here. Think carefully, maybe what you see as a large number of variables can be reduced to just one or two compact structs.

In general avoid as much as possible the use of global variables. Use them only as the last resource to export something to other modules and when the use of any other solution implies a performance lost.